# MikTeX Installation

Tags: errors, miktex2.9

I installed `MikTeX` on Windows 10 (64bit) in order to practice LaTeX. However when I am opening the command prompt and typing latex there it is showing an error. What should I do ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide some detail information about the error you encounter.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Did you deactivate your antivirus during installation?

Comment: Have you checkt your environmental Variable? And it might help if you postet the exact error message.

Comment: Try `texify filename.tex` if that is the name of your source document.  However, rather than running from the command line, the interface through the supplied editor `TeXworks` is very good.  You just click on the green triangle in the upper left, when your source document is in your TeXworks edit window.

Answer (score 1):

Its strange that the command line does not respond to the **latex** command. I suspect you might have unchecked an option while installing.

In any case, there are two ways (+one) to try out and start learning latex:

a) **The "Hard"** (if you want to use latex in the command line)

add the path of the miktex bin folder to the path of your machine

b) **The "Easy"** (if you just want to try latex without the cli hassle).

Just install an IDE like Texstudio, Texmaker, or a few others (free and commercial) available.

c) **The "Easiest"**  (if you want to learn latex without installing/updating anything on your pc)

Just to the [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) create an account and start trying things out.

I didn't bundle the third option, with the other because you already have a working miktex installation.